# How can a function have multiple outputs?

Tags: functions, vectors

Quoting Wikipedia (from
[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables) page)-

> Functions with multiple outputs are often written as vector-valued functions.

How is it possible for a function to give multiple outputs?

Comment: Depends on what you call "output". To me, a vector-valued function has a single output.

Comment: Yes. It should have a single output but Wikipedia denies it.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what Wikipedia says. A vector space may have multiple dimensions, but a vector is still a single *value* in that space. Consider for example that any complex function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ has as "*output*" a complex number $z$, which can also be regarded as a real $(x,y)$ pair.

Comment: A function has just one output, but this output may have many dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One such function is $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2\\ x \to (3x+2,4x-1)$

It is important to note that when one says multiple outputs, it is not that there are several alternative outputs, there is a set or ordered sequence of outputs. You can view the output as a single sequence or as several numbers.  When you talk of multiple outputs you are viewing it as several numbers.  When you talk about a vector valued function, you view the output as one sequence. That is the spirit of the comments you have received.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I wanted to define a "function" that takes a real number as input and returns two things: the input rounded down and the input rounded up. Strictly speaking, a function should only return one value. I can "cheat" however by defining the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ where $f(x) = (\lfloor x \rfloor, \lceil x \rceil)$. Since $f$ takes a real number as input and gives a *single* ordered pair as output, we are still respecting the definition of a function.